# Ui-grid show one column data into another

Tags: angularjs

I am working on ui-grid i have created a column definition as

```
name: 'id', 
displayName: 'Code',  
enableCellEdit: false,
cellTemplate : '<a href=\'#app/instrument-screen\?id={{COL_FIELD}}\'  ui-sref-active=\'active\' class=\'btn btn-success btn-sm\'>{{COL_FIELD}}</a>'
```

Its working fine, But their is another field in data array objects that is link_code
I would like to make the cell template as

```
name :'<a href=\'#app/instrument-screen\?id={{link_code}}\'  ui-sref-active=\'active\' class=\'btn btn-success btn-sm\'>{{id}}</a>'
```

any help
Thank you
Babji

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: data is like this

[{
        "_id": "56b9e68c471bfbc01c546f70",
        "id": "K010001",
    },
{
        "_id": "56b9e68c471bfbc01c546f70",
        "id": "K010001",
    },]


like to  <a href=_id >id</a>